# Using a custom function in Data Validation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use a custom function developed in Google Script to validate a value in the spreadsheet.

[image: For a cell I add a custom function call]

However I get a response: There is a problem "Enter a value that satisfies the formula: =validateContent()"

The function itself has not been called at all.

Am I pushing Google Spreadsheet validation too far here with custom function?
I was expecting my function to return true or false, is that how it is suppose to work?

```
function validateContent() {

  var val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getValue();

  if (val == value) return true;

  return false;

}
```

Comment: Sorry. I thought I have posted a comment already. C8 cell is just an example. It can be any cell that I want to validate.

Comment: There is a function that compare it to a different source and returns true or false depends whether it is valid or not. As mentioned though, the function has not even been called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to validate the current cell input it is useful to follow the pattern suggested by google:

```
=ISODD(C8)
```

In your case:

```
=validateContent(C8)
```

The validation generator is smart enough to translate the cell reference correctly to all other cells! I.e if this validation is applied to C8:C100 the validation of cell C42 will read `=ISODD(C42)`.

Still, I have found that custom functions seem not to work in validation! See the following example: 
[image: Example of faulty validation using custom functions]

In this screenshot the cell G2 uses a custom validation function (`=ssvDataVerify(G2)`), which evaluates to TRUE but is shown as invalid (red corner)! As a proof, the data value of cell I2 is `=ssvDataVerify(G2)`. Now the validation if I2 is =I2, which now is shown as correctly validated!

I conclude that currently custom functions are not implemented to work with validation.

Comment: This is true, but you could do the above where another column holds the output of your custom function and set the validation formula to check that the respective row of column I in this case == TRUE. i.e. "=(I2 == TRUE)"

Comment: I don't think this is the right approach you need to use the validation builder

Answer (score 5):

Currently, functions cannot be used in validations, but there is a workaround:

- Use your custom function in some cell, let's say *B2*: `=validateContent(A2)`.
- Add a validation to cell *A2* with the criteria `Custom Formula is` -> `=B2`.

Answer (score 4):

I also believe that custom functions don't work for data validation.

I created a function to check a string value , against a list of RegExp and it didn't worked:

```
function vaidate(){
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
  var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('=checkValid(A1)').build();
  range.setDataValidation(validation);
}


function checkValid(text){
  var regexs = [/\|{2,}/g,/\.{2,}/g,];
  var valid = true;
  for(var i=0;i<regexs.length;i++){
    if(testString(text,regexs[i])){
      valid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

function testString(str, regex){
  try{
     var localRegex = regex;
     return localRegex.test(str);
  }catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Spyros Theodosis, did you finally get it working?
Hope so.
Could you please so kind to share it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :)

The idea is to build the validation rule once the cell is edited

```
function onEdit(e){
  const isValid = validateValue(e.value);
  const rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation("Yep")
   // You can use any function but i believe you only need to use "EQ" with boolean 
  .requireFormulaSatisfied('=EQ("'+isValid+'","TRUE")')
   // Your help message
  .setHelpText('Please Enter "123" :P')
   // Building the rule 
  .build();
  e.range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function validateValue(value){
  // do what ever you want ;)
  return value === "123";
}
```